# C++: perfect transparent wrapping of base types into a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, ambiguous

I'm trying to develop a class which perfectly wraps base types so that one can use them exactly like normal, yet also extend them / add new functionality (c++11/c++14/etc are just fine).  So far I haven't succeeded.  Here's an example of what I'm running into (here I'm only implementing the plus operator, but I'd ultimately implement them all):

```
template <class T>
class N
{
public:
  N() {};
  N(int _var) : var(_var) {};

  template<typename U = T,
           typename Arg,
           typename Return = 
           typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, long double>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, long double>::value, long double, 
            typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, double>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, double>::value, double, 
             typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, float>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, float>::value, float, 
              typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned long long>::value || std::is_unsigned<Arg>::value, unsigned long long, 
               typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, long long>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, long long>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned long long>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, unsigned long long>::value, long long, 
                typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned long>::value || std::is_unsigned<Arg>::value, unsigned long, 
                 typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, long>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, long>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned long>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, unsigned long>::value, long, 
                  typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned int>::value || std::is_unsigned<Arg>::value, unsigned int, 
                   typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, int>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, int>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned int>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, unsigned int>::value, int, 
                    typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned short>::value || std::is_unsigned<Arg>::value, unsigned short, 
                     typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, short>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, short>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned short>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, unsigned short>::value, short, 
                      typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned char>::value || std::is_unsigned<Arg>::value, unsigned char, 
                       typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, char>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, char>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, unsigned char>::value || std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<Arg>::type, unsigned char>::value, char, 
                        typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<U>::type, bool>::value, bool, void
                                                 >::type 
                                                >::type 
                                               >::type 
                                              >::type 
                                             >::type 
                                            >::type 
                                           >::type 
                                          >::type 
                                         >::type 
                                        >::type 
                                       >::type 
                                      >::type 
                                     >::type 
                                    >::type 
          >
  N<Return> operator+(const N<Arg>& i) const
    { return var+i; };

//#define CONVERSION(x)   template<typename U = T, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<U, x>::value >::type> operator x() const { return var; };
#define CONVERSION(x)   operator x() const { return var; };
  CONVERSION(bool);
  CONVERSION(char);
  CONVERSION(unsigned char);
  CONVERSION(short);
  CONVERSION(unsigned short);
  CONVERSION(int);
  CONVERSION(unsigned int);
  CONVERSION(long);
  CONVERSION(unsigned long);
  CONVERSION(long long);
  CONVERSION(unsigned long long);
  CONVERSION(float);
  CONVERSION(double);
  CONVERSION(long double);

  T var;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  N<short> n1;
  N<int> n2;
  int d = n1;
  n1 + n2;
  return 0;
}
```

So, basically as you can see I'm spelling out for it the basic logic for minimum lossless conversion between types in the series of conditionals.  But running this one gets:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘N<Return> N<T>::operator+(const N<Arg>&) const [with U = short int; Arg = int; Return = int; T = short int]’:
test.cpp:2542:8:   required from here
test.cpp:2507:17: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘const short int’ and ‘const N<int>’)
     { return var+i; };
                 ^
test.cpp:2507:17: note: candidate: operator+(int, int) <built-in>
test.cpp:2507:17: note: candidate: operator+(int, unsigned int) <built-in>
test.cpp:2507:17: note: candidate: operator+(int, long int) <built-in>
test.cpp:2507:17: note: candidate: operator+(int, long unsigned int) <built-in>
test.cpp:2507:17: note: candidate: operator+(int, long long int) <built-in>
test.cpp:2507:17: note: candidate: operator+(int, long long unsigned int) <built-in>
test.cpp:2507:17: note: candidate: operator+(int, float) <built-in>
test.cpp:2507:17: note: candidate: operator+(int, double) <built-in>
test.cpp:2507:17: note: candidate: operator+(int, long double) <built-in>
```

...because the conversion operators can all be called, it the compiler considers all of those to be equally valid options to my explicitly spelled out conversion. Now, if we switch to the commented-out conversion macro so that only a single conversion operator is enabled for each type, we instead get:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:2541:11: error: cannot convert ‘N<short int>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
   int d = n1;
           ^
```

... because the compiler refuses to convert to short and then cast that to int, it demands explicit direct conversion operators.

I know obviously I can do this by using explicit casts in the main function. But that's not the point, the point is *transparent* wrapping, a class that behaves just like base types (which don't demand explicit casting).

Is that physically impossible in C++ as it stands?  :(

Comment: You should probably replace that monstrous `conditional` pudding with some type traits. Also, a pich of `using`-declarations will get rid of the `typename ...::type` stuff.

Comment: Type traits doesn't actually make it simpler because you still need all of the types for Return and at least one condition for them spelled out, in a fallthrough manner.  And this is a side issue anyway.  That mess will just be rolled into a define, I won't have to spell it out every time.

Comment: So you embarked on this very ambitious task without knowing whether it's possible. I don't think it is. Operator `.` is not overloadable. For starters.

Comment: Do you want to wrap *anything*, or just fundamental/builtin types?

Comment: Just fundamental builtin types. No need to wrap ".".  And does this look like a monstrous amount of work undertaken so far?

Comment: Instead of writing down the promotion rules yourself, couldn't you just use decltype? [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f25d6d6f94c9f60)

Comment: Also, your rules seem far from lossless - `unsigned int + unsigned anything -> unsigned int` ?

Comment: Melak: Good point about decltype, I'll switch to that.  Unfortunately your example doesn't quite do the trick.  Try "1 + n1".  The compiler is permitting assignment of a Wrap object with an integer as the lhs (int d = n1) but not addition of a Wrap object with an integer as the lhs (1 + n1).  :(

Comment: I have to wonder, what is it you plan on doing with this that you can't do with the fundamental types themselves?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it everyone!  It's not the prettiest code, but it seems to work.  First off, I'll note that I broke the problem down into two variants: "StrongNumber", where it tries to always return a wrapped numeric class; and "WeakNumber", where it tries always to return a base type.  The key was - what makes it ugly - avoiding templates.  Templates just lead to compiler confusion.

```
template <class T>
class StrongNumber
{
public:
  StrongNumber() {};
  StrongNumber(const T& _var) : var(_var) {};
  StrongNumber(const StrongNumber<T>& i) : var(i.var) {};

  #define DECLARE_HELPER(x, y) \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<long double>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };  \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<double>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };   \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<float>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };    \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<unsigned long long>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };   \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<long long>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };    \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<unsigned long>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };\
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<long>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };     \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<unsigned int>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); }; \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<int>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };      \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<unsigned short>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };   \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<short>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };    \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<unsigned char>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };\
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<char>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };     \
  auto operator x (const StrongNumber<bool>& i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i.var)>(var x i.var); };     \
  auto operator x (const long double i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };         \
  auto operator x (const double i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };              \
  auto operator x (const float i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };               \
  auto operator x (const unsigned long long i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };      \
  auto operator x (const long long i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };           \
  auto operator x (const unsigned long i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };           \
  auto operator x (const long i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };                \
  auto operator x (const unsigned int i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };            \
  auto operator x (const int i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };             \
  auto operator x (const unsigned short i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };          \
  auto operator x (const short i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };               \
  auto operator x (const unsigned char i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };           \
  auto operator x (const char i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };                \
  auto operator x (const bool i) y { return StrongNumber<decltype(var x i)>(var x i); };

  #define DECLARE(x)       DECLARE_HELPER(x, )
  #define DECLARE_CONST(x) DECLARE_HELPER(x, const)
  #define DECLARE_UNARY(x) auto operator x () { return StrongNumber<decltype(x var)>(x var); };
  #define DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(x) auto operator x () const { return StrongNumber<decltype(x var)>(x var); };

  operator T() const { return var; };

  DECLARE_CONST(%);
  DECLARE_CONST(+);
  DECLARE_CONST(-);
  DECLARE_CONST(*);
  DECLARE_CONST(/);
  DECLARE_CONST(&);
  DECLARE_CONST(|);
  DECLARE_CONST(^);
  DECLARE_CONST(<<);
  DECLARE_CONST(>>);
  DECLARE(=);
  DECLARE(+=);
  DECLARE(-=);
  DECLARE(*=);
  DECLARE(/=);
  DECLARE(&=);
  DECLARE(|=);
  DECLARE(^=);
  DECLARE(<<=);
  DECLARE(>>=);
  DECLARE_CONST(==);
  DECLARE_CONST(!=);
  DECLARE_CONST(>);
  DECLARE_CONST(<);
  DECLARE_CONST(>=);
  DECLARE_CONST(<=);
  DECLARE_UNARY(++);
  DECLARE_UNARY(--);
  DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(+);
  DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(-);
  DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(~);
  DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(!);
  explicit operator std::string() const { return std::to_string(var); };
  static int size() { return sizeof(T); };

  T var;
};

template <class T>
class WeakNumber
{
public:
  WeakNumber() {};
  WeakNumber(const T& _var) : var(_var) {};
  WeakNumber(const WeakNumber<T>& i) : var(i.var) {};

  #undef DECLARE_HELPER
  #define DECLARE_HELPER(x, y) \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<long double>& i) y { return var x i.var; }; \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<double>& i) y { return var x i.var; };      \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<float>& i) y { return var x i.var; };       \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<unsigned long long>& i) y { return var x i.var; };  \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<long long>& i) y { return var x i.var; };   \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<unsigned long>& i) y { return var x i.var; };   \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<long>& i) y { return var x i.var; };        \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<unsigned int>& i) y { return var x i.var; };    \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<int>& i) y { return var x i.var; };     \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<unsigned short>& i) y { return var x i.var; };  \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<short>& i) y { return var x i.var; };       \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<unsigned char>& i) y { return var x i.var; };   \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<char>& i) y { return var x i.var; };        \
  auto operator x (const WeakNumber<bool>& i) y { return var x i.var; };        \
  auto operator x (const long double i) y { return var x i; };          \
  auto operator x (const double i) y { return var x i; };           \
  auto operator x (const float i) y { return var x i; };            \
  auto operator x (const unsigned long long i) y { return var x i; };       \
  auto operator x (const long long i) y { return var x i; };            \
  auto operator x (const unsigned long i) y { return var x i; };        \
  auto operator x (const long i) y { return var x i; };             \
  auto operator x (const unsigned int i) y { return var x i; };         \
  auto operator x (const int i) y { return var x i; };              \
  auto operator x (const unsigned short i) y { return var x i; };       \
  auto operator x (const short i) y { return var x i; };            \
  auto operator x (const unsigned char i) y { return var x i; };        \
  auto operator x (const char i) y { return var x i; };             \
  auto operator x (const bool i) y { return var x i; };

  #undef DECLARE
  #undef DECLARE_CONST
  #undef DECLARE_UNARY
  #undef DECLARE_UNARY_CONST
  #define DECLARE(x)       DECLARE_HELPER(x, )
  #define DECLARE_CONST(x) DECLARE_HELPER(x, const)
  #define DECLARE_UNARY(x) auto operator x () { return x var; };
  #define DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(x) auto operator x () const { return x var; };

  operator T() const { return var; };

  DECLARE_CONST(%);
  DECLARE_CONST(+);
  DECLARE_CONST(-);
  DECLARE_CONST(*);
  DECLARE_CONST(/);
  DECLARE_CONST(&);
  DECLARE_CONST(|);
  DECLARE_CONST(^);
  DECLARE_CONST(<<);
  DECLARE_CONST(>>);
  DECLARE(=);
  DECLARE(+=);
  DECLARE(-=);
  DECLARE(*=);
  DECLARE(/=);
  DECLARE(&=);
  DECLARE(|=);
  DECLARE(^=);
  DECLARE(<<=);
  DECLARE(>>=);
  DECLARE_CONST(==);
  DECLARE_CONST(!=);
  DECLARE_CONST(>);
  DECLARE_CONST(<);
  DECLARE_CONST(>=);
  DECLARE_CONST(<=);
  DECLARE_UNARY(++);
  DECLARE_UNARY(--);
  DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(+);
  DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(-);
  DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(~);
  DECLARE_UNARY_CONST(!);
  // A couple more just because they're useful
  explicit operator std::string() const { return std::to_string(var); }; 
  static int size() { return sizeof(T); };

  T var;
};
```

So, I wrote a test function here:

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
T3 foo()
{
  StrongNumber<T1> n1;
  StrongNumber<T2> n2;
  T3 d = n1;
  n1 + n2;
  n1 + 1;
  n1 + 1.0;
  d = d + n1;
  d += 1 + n1;
  d += 1.0 + n1;
  return d;
}
```

... then repeatedly called it as:

```
std::cout << foo<short, long long, int>() << std::endl;
```

... and so such.  I had it try every single combination of base types (I wrote a quick bash script to print them all out) and none gave compile errors.

So, I think this is solved!  :)  I swear, I've needed a class like this on one in three C++ programs I've ever written and written a bunch of half-satisfactory ones in the past... so this is going to get a lot of use!